# Calculating the size of monochrome binary image

Tags: image, image-processing, binary

I created a **monochrome bitmap image** and stored it in secondary memory. The dimension of the image is 484 * 114. In monochrome each pixel of the image is represented by 1 bit so the size of the image should be 6.7 kb . But when I check the size  by right on file  in OS , it is 7.18 KB , I need the explanation  why the size is different and not exact as I calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Because of overhead of headers for example; your bitmap won't only store the bits representing your image but also (meta)information containing information such as width, height, bits per plane etc. The actual bitmap data is just a bunch of bytes, without this (meta)information your image might as well be 114 x 484 instead of 484 x 114. Take a look at, for example, the [BMP fileformat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#File_structure).

Also, OS'es tend to round filesizes to particular block sizes (like 4Kib). Unless you state the exact filesize in bytes, OS and filetype all we can do is guess.

Comment: There's not only meta but also data aligning by 8 bytes (instead of 61 bytes in non-aligned variant  image string have size of 64 bytes).

Comment: @Eddy_Em: That would be dependant of the used format ofcourse. For all we know sidstuff used a "homegrown" format (but then again, sidstuff would've known about headers/metainfo and not asked this question in the first place). Also, depending on the format, compression like RLE might be used. There are many factors that can have an effect in the final filesize. I just opted to name two of the most obvious.